# Create dictionary key and value pair from nested JSON values

Tags: python, json, loops

I am attempting to create a dictionary by looping through a weather JSON file.

I want the key to be date and the value to be temperature from the nested "hours" in the JSON.

combined_temperature_hour = {date, temperature}

As I loop through the JSON file I can get the individual items but I can't figure out how to grab the two values and put them together in a (key, value) pair.

```
combined_temperature_hour = {}

for d in days:
    for hours in d["hours"]:
        hourly = hours.get('datetimeEpoch')
        dia_y_hora = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(hourly))
        complete_date.append(dia_y_hora)

        h_temp = hours.get('temp')
        hourly_temperature.append(h_temp)

        #combined
        combined = {complete_date, hourly_temperature}
        print(combined)
```

JSON

```
"days":[
      {
         "datetime":"2021-01-01",
         "datetimeEpoch":1609484400,
         "tempmax":36.9,
         "tempmin":32.4,
         "temp":34.7,
         "hours":[
            {
               "datetime":"00:00:00",
               "datetimeEpoch":1609484400,
               "temp":32.9,
            },
            {
               "datetime":"01:00:00",
               "datetimeEpoch":1609488000,
               "temp":33.2,
            },
            {
               "datetime":"02:00:00",
               "datetimeEpoch":1609491600,
               "temp":33.2,
            }
         ]
      }
```

This is what I would like the dictionary to look like after the loop

```
combined_temperature_hour = {`2021-01-24 05:00:00`: '25.1', `2021-01-24 06:00:00`: '26.2'}
```

I have tried grabbing the list for temperature and hour and combining into a dictionary them after the loop but I noticed that I am missing values and they are probably incorrect pairs.

Comment: Are you sure you want the temperature to be the key? What if there are multiple times with the same tempeature?

Comment: It would make more sense for the time to be the key.

Comment: That is a good point. I hadn't thought about duplicate temperatures. I should have date be the key. I will update my question to reverse that. Thank you @Barmar

Comment: This is a basic dictionary operation: `combined_temperature_hour[dia_y_hora] = h_temp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your json as a dictionary first into a variable `a`
(I changed some of the mismatching brackets in your json)

```
a = {"days":[
      {
         "datetime":"2021-01-01",
         "datetimeEpoch":1609484400,
         "tempmax":36.9,
         "tempmin":32.4,
         "temp":34.7,
         "hours":[
            {
               "datetime":"00:00:00",
               "datetimeEpoch":1609484400,
               "temp":32.9,
            },
            {
               "datetime":"01:00:00",
               "datetimeEpoch":1609488000,
               "temp":33.2,
            },
            {
               "datetime":"02:00:00",
               "datetimeEpoch":1609491600,
               "temp":33.2,
            }
         ]
       }
    ]
}
```

Then you can have the expected output from the following code:

```
combined_temperature_hour = {}
for date in a['days']:
  for hour in date['hours']:
    combined_temperature_hour[date['datetime']+' '+hour['datetime']] = hour['temp']
```

Comment: This worked thank you but I had to modify the code a bit to work for me. 

        combined_temperature_hour[dia_y_hora] = hours['temp']